Wordpress Astra theme not loading on site
I develop my site on Wordpress and I am using Astra theme.
When I am logged into Wordpress, I can develop Astra things however I want and I am able to see them when I go to site preview (still logged in to Wordpress)
But when I try to see my site as a not logged in user (f.e. through incognito), I cannot see Astra theme at all.
(using wordpress.org on docker)
Tried to migrate wordpress to AWS Lightsail, but don't see Astra theme there either.

Ok, the solution was to disable "Comming soon mode" in Spectra

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
